# Dynamically Rendering a JSON String to a Table in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I need help mapping a complex C# object to a table dynamically, without manually defining a model. I'm using ASP.NET 4.5.

So I am using JSON.NET to serialize my complex C# object into a JSON object with

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject, Formatting.Indented);
```

This object is being read in dynamically from an external API. It includes complex attributes, like dictionaries, as well as standard strings, integers, etc. I input in a key and it returns the C# object.

I can't manually map the object to a model, since the object does change frequently with development, and needs to be extensible despite changes in the C# object. What is the best way to map this JSON object to a table? Essentially need to be able to render the JSON serialized from the object into a readable table with ASP.NET.

Thanks so much!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142495/deserialize-json-into-c-sharp-dynamic-object You can find solution

Comment: http://marianoguerra.github.io/json.human.js/